# Delete Row & Images from Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am needing to delete a column and images in Excel all in one click. I have the Macro that allows me to delete the images, but it doesnt delete the column.

```
Sub RemoveDrawingObjects()

 'Removes any drawing / chart / shapes / ocx control objects from the active worksheet.

Dim iCount As Integer
Dim Embedded_Objects As Integer

Embedded_Objects = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

For iCount = Embedded_Objects To 1 Step -1
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(iCount).Delete
Next iCount

End Sub
```

This is the code I am using to delete the Images and it works great, how would I have it delete the highlighted column.

Any advice or tips are welcome.

My tip was delete the images and then just delete the column but they are wanting it all in one click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991007/excel-deleting-images-when-deleting-a-row

Answer (score 1):

if the column is already selected, then:

```
Sub RemoveDrawingObjects()

'Removes any drawing / chart / shapes / ocx control objects from the active worksheet.

Dim iCount As Integer
Dim Embedded_Objects As Integer

Embedded_Objects = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

For iCount = Embedded_Objects To 1 Step -1
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(iCount).Delete
Next iCount

'delete active column
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

also, an easier way to delete all shapes is:

```
Sub RemoveDrawingObjects()

'Removes any drawing / chart / shapes / ocx control objects from the active worksheet.
Dim shp_fordelete As Shape
For Each shp_fordelete In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    shp_fordelete.Delete
Next shp_fordelete

'delete active column
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```